# docker-compose spring boot cannot connect to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

When I make the docker-compose file only contains MySQL  and I run the application from Intellij or from the .jar file it works fine, but when i'm trying to get it running using docker compose I get this error
`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

My dockerfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13
ADD ./build/libs/AppointmentsSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: appointmentSystem
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.sulimanLab'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '13'

configurations {

    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "6.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/appointmentSystem
    username: root
    password: rootpassword
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    database: MYSQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
server:
  port: 8081
```

The error

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Github\AppointmentsSystem - Copy> docker-compose.exe up
Creating network "appointmentssystem-copy_default" with the default driver
Creating appointmentssystem-copy_mysql_1 ... done                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Creating appointmentssystem-copy_app_1   ... done                                                                                                                                                                                                                              Attaching to appointmentssystem-copy_mysql_1, appointmentssystem-copy_app_1
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05 17:05:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05 17:05:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05 17:05:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.28-1debian9 started.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.307944Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.313597Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.28) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321895Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321911Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321914Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321916Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321919Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.321921Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.322089Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.322160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.323705Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.349344Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.351768Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.420065Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.525183Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.527734Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.735100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.744572Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.744744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.745330Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.796296Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.28 started; log sequence number 12442260
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.796835Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.797225Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.878505Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.878712Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.898316Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.900205Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.910728Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.911146Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.911674Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.912095Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.917607Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:11.947376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200105 17:05:11
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:12.631614Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
mysql_1  | 2020-01-05T17:05:12.632095Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1  | Version: '5.7.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
app_1    |
app_1    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
app_1    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
app_1    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
app_1    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
app_1    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
app_1    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
app_1    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)
app_1    |
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:13.641  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.A.AppointmentsSystemApplication      : Starting AppointmentsSystemApplication on 185f7c998f26 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:13.660  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.A.AppointmentsSystemApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:14.985  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:15.132  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 131ms. Found 5 repository interfaces.
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:15.844  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:16.390  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:16.416  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:16.417  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:16.533  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:16.533  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2786 ms
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:17.203  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:17.317  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.8.Final}
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:17.565  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:17.807  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:18.033 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
app_1    |
app_1    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app_1    |
app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar!/:5.4.8.Final]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
app_1    |      at com.sulimanLab.AppointmentsSystem.AppointmentsSystemApplication.main(AppointmentsSystemApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[app.jar:na]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[app.jar:na]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[app.jar:na]
app_1    |      at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[app.jar:na]
app_1    | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
app_1    |
app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      ... 57 common frames omitted
app_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
app_1    |      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585) ~[na:na]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
app_1    |      ... 60 common frames omitted
app_1    |
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:18.035  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
app_1    |
app_1    | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:18.068  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:19.454  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
app_1    | 2020-01-05 17:05:19.462 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
app_1    |
app_1    | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception. Has the mySQL docker image successfully been started? Are you able to connect to the database with other tools?

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/appointmentSystem`

Comment: @michalk it doesn't work

Comment: Again: please post the full stack trace and check that the database container is running and accessible, e.g. by using a command-line tool.

Comment: I couldn't put the full stack trace of the exception because it was over the characters limit

Comment: Don't use `links`, it is a [legacy setting and may be removed in the future](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/). @Yossef619 yet again, can you verify that the database container is running and accessible?

Comment: @Turing85 the database container is running and accessible

Comment: @Yossef619 First create a new docker network. Ensure both `app` and `mysql` are within the same container. Then change jdbc url to `jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/appointmentSystem`. Even if you added port as `3308:3306` the mysql in docker container is still running on 3306 port and it is mapped to host port of 3308. So if you can connect directly using jdbc url above, and connect to database container on port 3306 (as long as both docker container are on same network)

Comment: Also add `restart: unless-stopped` to the application container. This is because first time application starts the database may not be already started. Hence application will fail with connection error. But if you add the above restart flag, then application will restart and try connecting to db. Once db is up, then application will start running